# Apache Rewrite middle parameter value

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to save users from having to re-share outdated links:

OLD:

```
https://mysite:443/myoldapplication/asp/Main.aspx?parm1=Main.aspx.999&parm2=old01&parm3=firstname%20lastname&share=1
```

NEW:

```
https://mysite:443/mynewapplication/servlet/Web?parm1=Web.999&parm2=new02&parm3=firstname%20lastname&share=1
```

I have tried to chain together a set of rules, but it appears that the original string gets tested as a separate case against the old URL, not cumulatively. So, apply first rule, then get result, apply second rule to it, get result, apply third rule.

```
RewriteRule myoldapplication/asp/Main.aspx mynewapplication/servlet/Web [C]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)Main\.aspx(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1parm1=Web.999%2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)old01(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1new02$2 [L]
```

Ideas?

Comment: What exactly does _“but it does not handle the %20(spaces)”_ mean? You might simply need to set the `B` flag to get them properly encoded again afterwards …?
 http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: Hello, i edited the request to be more accurate.  The first rule changes the asp for servlet, the second attempts to change the value of an aspx, the third to change a parameter value.  Sorry for the confusion CBroe.

Comment: Now you just completely removed any mention of "spaces", and your question does not even contain an actual problem description any more ... so, what exactly goes wrong with this and where ...?

Comment: I am not sure [C]haining a rule with the next one works this way, whether putting a RewriteCond in between works or actually does the expected thing. I don't think this needs any chaining or multiple rules, if you just match the query string format of `parm1=...&parm2=...&parm3=...&share=1` in a RewriteCond, capturing the `...` parts, and then have one RewriteRule that simply matches for the URL path `myoldapplication/asp/Main.aspx`, and then assembles the new URL from the captured condition matches.

Comment: @cbroe `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)parm1=Main\.aspx\.999(.*)parm2=(?:[^&=]+)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^bix/asp/Main\.aspx(.*) myapplication/servlet/Web ?%1parm1=Web\.999%2parm2=newserver%3`